# Etymological origins of the Hindi word Afeem

Tags: etymology, arabic, hindustani

I have been trying to find the origins of the Hindi word **अफ़ीम** "*Afeem*". It means *opium*.

The **Rajpal Hindi Shabdakosh** gives the origin of "afeem" as Arabic:
[https://hi.oxforddictionaries.com/परिभाषा/अफ़ीम](https://hi.oxforddictionaries.com/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%BE/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%BC%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AE)

I have been lead to this word in Arabic:

> أفيون

Beyond that I have not been able to further find its origin. If someone will be willing to point me to its Arabic etymology that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ultimate origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%84%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD) of that word is Ancient Greek `ὄπιον` (ópion, "opium") which is a diminutive form of `ὀπός` (opós, “juice”). It was borrowed into Persian as `اپیون` (apiyūn) and from Persian it was borrowed into Arabic as `أفيون` (ʾafyūn).

Comment: *ὁπός (*hopós),: from Proto-Indo-European *sokʷos (“juice, resin”).

Answer (score 0):

The Persian-Arabic borrowings were rare (unlike the borrowings in opposite directions, that is, from Arabic into Persian).

The data in Wiktionary suggesting that borrowing direction is based upon a sourse of the XIXth century.

It is more likely therefore that the Arabic word derives from the root [و ف ي](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%88_%D9%81_%D9%8A#Arabic) (w+f+y) meaning 'to (over)fullfill'.

Comment: The derivation of Arabic ʼafyūn from Greek opion is completely unproblematic (with or without a Persian intermediary).

Comment: ....whereas the derivation from وفى is semantically and phonologically impossible.

Comment: Any proof? The semanitcs are clear and fourth form mazdars beign with an '.

Comment: The form IV maṣdar of وفى is ʼīfāʼ ايفاء. It means “payment” and the like.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that Arabic أفيون *ʾafyūn* was borrowed into Hindi-Urdu and later remodelled on the English *opium*, explaining the final *m* in *afīm*. This would also make sense historically since the British presence in South Asia brought widespread commercial opium cultivation.